# removeClass and addClass simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, class

```
return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
```

I'm returning a function value and I need to both `removeClass` and `addClass` at the same time without writing two statements, wonder if thats possible?

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').end().addClass('invalid');
```

Comment: don't get it. what do you want to be returned?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps if you also explained what the overall goal was, and how the return value is intended to be used, it would help clear things up.

Comment: question... first line of question... answer... first answer, same line... seems legit...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your previous code is correct :

```
return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
```

If this is not working there might be other problem with your code. Post your complete code.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `toggleClass` : http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
return $('.card-number').toggleClass('valid invalid');
```

Comment: I've found that toggle is not too reliable, also it wouldn't work well in this case.

Comment: The `.toggleClass()` function isn't suited if you want to make sure that certain classes are or aren't on an element (which seems to be the case here).

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing via Attribute:

```
return $('.card-number').attr('class', 'invalid');
```

It replace the whole class attribute adding only "invalid".

Comment: aha, good tip to remember but in this case I have other classes too

Comment: ok, in your question there is only one class. Extend your question and we will find the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
       return $('.card-number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
```

Comment: Please check other answers before posting your answer!?

Comment: ok after posting this only i saw the previous post.